# Can't connect to vncserver via bash script in cronjob

Tags: bash, cron, vnc, vnc-server

I'm trying to connect to a vncserver via a bash script that is started by root's (sudo -s) crontab. Unfortunately I always get:

> Client is not authorized to connect to ServerException in thread "main" java.awt.AW\ TError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':10' as the value of the DISPLAY \ variable.

Using vncviewer and connecting with ip-addr:10, I can easily connect.

When I run the bash script manually, I am able to connect too.

I did echo the $USER in the bash script when run in the cronjob and that ended up being an empty string.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You may need the vncviewer `-passwd` flag, or need to do something with Xauth.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and don't see/don't know where the xauth file is. Also, I don't seem to need vncviewer --passwd flag when I just run on the bash script on the command line. It's only when I add it in as a cronjob that I get a not authorized exception